# RaiseEvent Issue while Converting Code C# to VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, wpf, vb.net, events

I have following C# function,

```
     private void btnSendtoGeoDecision_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<FenceModel> lst = new List<FenceModel>();
        int FencesInsert;

        foreach (FenceModel item in FenceList.SelectedItems)
        {
            lst.Add(item);
        }
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        //this is where the long running process should go
        worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
        {
            //no direct interaction with the UI is allowed from this method

            bool result = objFenceRepository.SendFences(lst, out FencesInsert);
            if (result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The total of {0} fences have been sent to Geo Decision.", FencesInsert));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The error occurs in sending fences to Geo Decision."));
            }

        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
        {
            //work has completed. you can now interact with the UI
           // _busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
        };
        //set the IsBusy before you start the thread
      //  _busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

And I Convert it into VB.NET Using Language Converter and It gave me below code

```
         Private Sub btnSendtoGeoDecision_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim lst As New List(Of FenceModel)()
        Dim FencesInsert As Integer

        For Each item As FenceModel In FenceList.SelectedItems
            lst.Add(item)
        Next
        Dim worker As New BackgroundWorker()
        'this is where the long running process should go
        worker.DoWork += Function(o, ea)
                             'no direct interaction with the UI is allowed from this method

                             Dim result As Boolean = objFenceRepository.SendFences(lst, FencesInsert)
                             If result Then
                                 MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The total of {0} fences have been sent to Geo Decision.", FencesInsert))
                             Else
                                 MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The error occurs in sending fences to Geo Decision."))

                             End If

                         End Function
        'work has completed. you can now interact with the UI
        ' _busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Function(o, ea)

                                     End Function
        'set the IsBusy before you start the thread
        '  _busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub
```

But when I build it, I get following two Errors, I know its asking me to use RaiseEvent since += equivalent to RaiseEvent in VB.Net, But can Anybody Show me how?

```
    'Public Event DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event. 

    'Public Event RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.
```

Comment: Have you tried Dim WithEvents worker As New BackgroundWorker() ?

Comment: Yes, I get build error "WithEvents is not valid on local variable declaration"

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this. See my answer for a more correct use of WithEvents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
AddHandler worker.DoWork, Sub(o, ea)
                            ' code here 
                          End Function

AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted, Sub(o, ea)
                                       ' code here 
                                      End Function
```

For your anonymous eventhandler to work.

Comment: Fancy I didn't know this syntax

Comment: Yeah it's just VB.NET's lambda syntax!

Answer (score 0):

If you need anonymous event handler follow Ric answer.

Otherwise you have to declare worker as a member variable of the class/module that includes your function like:

```
Private WithEvents worker As BackgroundWorker
```

And then you can create named function that handle your event like this:

```
Private Sub DoWorkHandler (sender As Object, args As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles worker.DoWork
```